# How to change mouse pointer in mode line or header line?

Tags: mode-line, mouse, header-line

The mouse pointer shape changes whether its over the buffer, over the mode line, or header line, if that exists.

How can I change the mouse pointer shapes for these different areas to something other than their defaults?

Comment: See the manual node on [Pointer Shape](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pointer-Shape.html) to get started.

Comment: I've already worked how to do this, for my purposes. I was mostly interested in setting the pointer in the header line, and I can do that by setting the pointer text property for the text in the header line.